# The ListenHear Game - Listen and type the word

Tags: javascript, html, quiz

What it does:

Speak a random word chosen from an array and ask the user to type the word in the box for 15 seconds

- If right, +1pts, reset the timer and go to next word.
- If wrong: do nothing.
- After 15 seconds: game over.

```css
    body {background-color: black; color: white;}
    .center {
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;

      margin: auto;
    }
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center class="center start">
  <h1>
    The ListenHear<br>Game<br><br><button class="w3-btn w3-green" onclick="play()">Play</button><button class="w3-btn w3-red" onclick="exit()">Exit</button>
  </h1>
</center>
<center class="center hidden">
  <h1 id="x"><x class="w3-red">There was an error.</x> </h1>
</center>
<script>
var read;
var time = 0;
var i = 0;
var words;
var c;
  $.getJSON( "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/khanh2003/ae6c144ed12aa4e6dce98c40163935d1/raw/9073f8a40a39ecbe02a38547f99bca9e3637660c/JSON.json", function( data ) {
    words=data;
    });
function play() {
$(".start").hide(function() {
$(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
$("#x")[0].innerHTML = "<i style='color:green'>Listen and fill in the blank the word(s).</i>";
setTimeout(game,2000);
});}
function game() {
  read = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
  $("#x")[0].innerHTML = "<input type=text onkeypress=check() style=width:100%></input><button onclick='speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(read));'>Again please!</button><br><div class='time'></div><br><button onclick=giveup()>Give up</button>";
$("input").focus();
speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(read));
time = 0;
  c=setInterval(function() {
  time=time+0.01;
  $(".time").text(Math.floor(15-time));
  if(time>15) {giveup();}
}, 10);
}
function check() {
  
  if ($("input")[0].value.toUpperCase() === read.toUpperCase()) {
    $("#x")[0].innerHTML = "<i style='color:green'>Correct! Score: "+(++i)+"</i>";
    time = 0;
    setTimeout(game,2000);
    clearInterval(c);
  }
}
function giveup() {
    $("#x")[0].innerHTML = "<i style='color:red'>Time's Up! Score: "+(i)+"<br>The word(s) are: "+read+"</i>";
    time=0;
    setTimeout(play,5000);
}
function exit() {$("body").slideUp(function() {window.close;});}
</script>
```

For those who are complaining [the code is broken](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33614189#33614189), the SpeechSynthesisAPI (the code depends on) doesn't have [good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-synthesis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `game()` calls `c=setInterval(…)`, which is balanced by `clearInterval(c)` in `check()`.  However, `giveup()` does not call `clearInterval(c)`.  As a result, if you just start the game but do nothing, then it gets ridiculously faster and faster.